# Cannot read property 'allDocs' after refreshing the page

Tags: angular, ionic2

**It seems that the connection to the CouchDB is getting reset when page is refreshed.**

I am working on a simple todo app with Couchdb and Pouchdb as seen on this [Blog](https://www.joshmorony.com/part-2-creating-a-multiple-user-app-with-ionic-2-pouchdb-couchdb/). Everything seems to work but I got problems when the HomePage is getting refreshed by clicking the browser refresh button. The data is pulled using a provider.

**home.ts** Loads data from **provider.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.DbProvider.getTodos().then((data) => {
    this.todos = data;
  });
}

getTodos() {
  if (this.data) {
    return Promise.resolve(this.data);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.db.allDocs({
      include_docs: true
    }).then((result) => {
      this.data = [];
      let doc = result.rows.map((row) => {
        this.data.push(row.doc);
      });
      resolve(this.data);

      this.db.changes({live: true, since: 'now', include_docs: true}).on('change', (change) => {
        this.handleChange(change);
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }); 
  });
}
```

**provider.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

@Injectable()
export class DbProvider {
  data: any;
  db: any;
  remote: any;

  constructor() {}
  init(details){
    this.db = new PouchDB('myDB');
    this.remote = details.userDBs.supertest;
    let options = {
      live: true,
      retry: true,
      continuous: true
    };
    this.db.sync(this.remote, options); 
    console.log(this.db);
  }
}
```

The error I am experiencing

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'allDocs' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'allDocs' of undefined
at provider.ts:61
at new t (polyfills.js:3)
at DbProvider.webpackJsonp.201.DbProvider.getTodos (provider.ts:59)
at HomePage.webpackJsonp.317.HomePage.ngOnInit (home.ts:38)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12095)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13598)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13541)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14413)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HomePage_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
at provider.ts:61
at new t (polyfills.js:3)
at DbProvider.webpackJsonp.201.DbProvider.getTodos (provider.ts:59)
at HomePage.webpackJsonp.317.HomePage.ngOnInit (home.ts:38)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12095)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13598)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13541)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14413)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HomePage_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
at c (polyfills.js:3)
at c (polyfills.js:3)
at polyfills.js:3
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
at o (polyfills.js:3)
at <anonymous>
```

Comment: where do u use `allDocs` property ?

Comment: Question has been edited. @SachilaRanawaka